# how to categorized different rows based on values of three columns in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame(my_df) that has 5 columns as below:

```
No.       Id        X       Y        Z
1      A2_A0CX      A2  2010-06-16  A00Z
2      A8_A076      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z
3      A8_A07B      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z
4      A8_A07I      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z
5      A8_A081      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z
6      AO_A03L      AO  2010-08-11  A056
7      AO_A0JE      AO  2010-08-11  A056
.        .          .       .         .
.        .          .       .         .
.        .          .       .         .
```

I want to categorize rows of my_df based on values of three columns including "X", "Y", and "Z". In other words, I want to find different batches of rows which the values of "X", "Y", and "Z" are similar and assign a label to each batch in a new column as below:

```
No.       Id         X     Y         Z        Cat
1      A2_A0CX      A2  2010-06-16  A00Z      cat1
2      A8_A076      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z      cat2
3      A8_A07B      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z      cat2
4      A8_A07I      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z      cat2
5      A8_A081      A8  2010-06-16  A00Z      cat2
6      AO_A03L      AO  2010-08-11  A056      cat3
7      AO_A0JE      AO  2010-08-11  A056      cat3
.        .           .      .        .          .
.        .           .      .        .          .
.        .           .      .        .          .
```

How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cur_group_id` from `dplyr` after grouping by the columns 'X', 'Y', 'Z'

```
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr)   
df2 <- df1 %>%
      group_by(X, Y, Z) %>%
      mutate(Cat = str_c('cat', cur_group_id())) %>%
      ungroup
```

-output

```
df2
# A tibble: 7 x 6
#    No. Id      X     Y          Z     Cat  
#  <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>
#1     1 A2_A0CX A2    2010-06-16 A00Z  cat1 
#2     2 A8_A076 A8    2010-06-16 A00Z  cat2 
#3     3 A8_A07B A8    2010-06-16 A00Z  cat2 
#4     4 A8_A07I A8    2010-06-16 A00Z  cat2 
#5     5 A8_A081 A8    2010-06-16 A00Z  cat2 
#6     6 AO_A03L AO    2010-08-11 A056  cat3 
#7     7 AO_A0JE AO    2010-08-11 A056  cat3
```

---

Or using `base R` with `match`

```
nm1 <- with(df1, paste(X, Y, Z))
df1$Cat <- paste0('cat', match(nm1, unique(nm1)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(No. = 1:7, Id = c("A2_A0CX", "A8_A076", "A8_A07B", 
"A8_A07I", "A8_A081", "AO_A03L", "AO_A0JE"), X = c("A2", "A8", 
"A8", "A8", "A8", "AO", "AO"), Y = c("2010-06-16", "2010-06-16", 
"2010-06-16", "2010-06-16", "2010-06-16", "2010-08-11", "2010-08-11"
), Z = c("A00Z", "A00Z", "A00Z", "A00Z", "A00Z", "A056", "A056"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Dear @akrun, I used your first solution and import "dplyr" library but I got this error: Error in cur_group_id() : could not find function "cur_group_id"

Comment: @Mohammad it may be that your `packageVersion('dplyr')` is less than 1.0.  Can you update the dplyr version?  thanks

Comment: Dear @akrun, my 'dplyr' package version is ‘0.8.3’ and based on your advice I have to update it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is using `factor` + `paste0`

```
within(df, Cat <- paste0("cat", as.integer(factor(paste0(X, Y, Z)))))
```

which gives

```
  No.      Id  X          Y    Z  Cat
1   1 A2_A0CX A2 2010-06-16 A00Z cat1
2   2 A8_A076 A8 2010-06-16 A00Z cat2
3   3 A8_A07B A8 2010-06-16 A00Z cat2
4   4 A8_A07I A8 2010-06-16 A00Z cat2
5   5 A8_A081 A8 2010-06-16 A00Z cat2
6   6 AO_A03L AO 2010-08-11 A056 cat3
7   7 AO_A0JE AO 2010-08-11 A056 cat3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(No. = 1:7, Id = c("A2_A0CX", "A8_A076", "A8_A07B", 
"A8_A07I", "A8_A081", "AO_A03L", "AO_A0JE"), X = c("A2", "A8",
"A8", "A8", "A8", "AO", "AO"), Y = c("2010-06-16", "2010-06-16",
"2010-06-16", "2010-06-16", "2010-06-16", "2010-08-11", "2010-08-11"
), Z = c("A00Z", "A00Z", "A00Z", "A00Z", "A00Z", "A056", "A056"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```